# Ubuntu 17.10 crashes to console, sometimes!

Tags: nvidia, gnome, 17.10, gdm, wayland

I have a fresh artful_x64, with preinstalled softwares, and experiencing GUI crash(using default wayland), and screen jumps to boot console log(at last line when it was booting up).

When I log back in, by pressing (alt+ctrl+f4) and executing `gdmflexiserver`, and GUI comes back at login screen, I can see my running programs before GUI lose, but when I try to logout, it informs that another user is logged in, which is me!!!

I even installed nVIDIA driver, but no different. Is there any workaround for this?

Hardware:Asus-K43SD & Asus-X550LC

Thanks

Comment: It may be a wayland problem, which can be avoided by switching to an xorg session at the login screen. Also, to avoid starting another gdm session, try `sudo systemctl gdm stop` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened again, I pressed `(alt+ctrl+f2)` accidentally and the session comes back!!!

Comment: I don't understand. Does this mean the problem described in the question went away?

Comment: the answer is just a solution to bypass the problem, not bug fix.