# Ubuntu 18.04 randomly freezes while working

Tags: 18.04, freeze

I have a problem with random freezing couple of times a week that I can't seem to solve. When I am working on the computer, most often when using a web browser, the whole computer freezes, and the only thing to do is manually restart the computer. The screen gets black and if it was audio the audio hangs for 10 seconds and then goes silent.

I tried both Firefox and Chrome but not Chromium. I have tried many things for this but these are the ones I remember, turn on/off IOMMU in BIOS, turn on/off power saving/ virtualization CPU feature in BIOS, downloaded a GPU driver from AMD (it did not help, so I deleted it), updated the kernel to 4.18.12. BIOS is the latest version.

**PC specs**

- Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.18.12
- CPU AMD FX 6300
- GPU AMD HD7950 x2 (crossfire)
- Motherboard Asus Crosshair V Formula-Z 990FX
- RAM Kingston HyperX 32GB (HX318C10FBK2/16 x2)
- SSD HyperX Savage 120GB
- PSU Corsair HX 1050W

Output from the logs before it freezes:

```
15:42:00 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
15:39:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
15:39:01 kernel: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
15:39:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
15:37:49 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
15:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
15:16:54 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
15:09:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
15:08:33 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
15:05:41 canonical-livep: No payload available.
15:04:22 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
15:03:36 anacron: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
15:03:36 systemd: Started Run anacron jobs.
15:02:16 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
14:57:37 dbus-daemon: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
14:57:12 gnome-keyring-d: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/2, but it's already registered
14:57:12 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.260' (uid=1000 pid=21109 comm="/opt/google/chrome/chrome --app=https://mail.googl")
14:56:00 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
14:53:56 dbus-daemon: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
14:53:54 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
14:53:31 gnome-keyring-d: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/2, but it's already registered
14:53:31 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.259' (uid=1000 pid=20245 comm="/opt/google/chrome/chrome --app=https://accounts.g")
14:53:28 gnomegmail.py: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
14:52:51 dbus-daemon: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
14:52:26 gnome-keyring-d: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/2, but it's already registered
14:52:26 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.258' (uid=1000 pid=19690 comm="/opt/google/chrome/chrome --app=https://accounts.g")
14:52:20 gnomegmail.py: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
14:51:49 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
14:39:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
14:39:01 kernel: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
14:39:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
14:37:11 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
14:33:17 systemd: Started Hostname Service.
14:33:17 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
14:33:16 systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
14:33:16 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.256' (uid=1000 pid=18728 comm="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox ")
14:33:00 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
14:30:49 firefox: (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:18850): dconf-WARNING **: 14:30:49.877: Unable to open /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
14:28:49 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
14:20:27 snapd: autorefresh.go:387: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
14:20:27 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
14:19:46 NetworkManager: <info>  [1539519586.2671] dhcp6 (enp3s0): state changed timeout -> done
14:19:32 dhclient: dhc6: send_packet6() sent -1 of 60 bytes
14:19:02 avahi-daemon: Registering new address record for 2a02:fe1:3000:6400:452a:9eb3:3d46:a6a8 on enp3s0.*.
14:19:02 dhclient: dhc6: send_packet6() sent -1 of 60 bytes
14:19:01 NetworkManager: <info>  [1539519541.3217] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
14:19:01 avahi-daemon: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a9bd:3918:1934:484f on enp3s0.
14:19:01 NetworkManager: <info>  [1539519541.3205] dhcp6 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 14064
14:18:22 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
14:17:34 gnome-shell: [AppIndicatorSupport-WARN] Item :1.70/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/psensor is already registered
14:17:34 polkitd: Operator of unix-session:1 successfully authenticated as unix-user:desktop to gain ONE-SHOT authorization for action org.freedesktop.udisks2.ata-smart-update for system-bus-name::1.75 [psensor] (owned by unix-user:desktop)
```

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              6
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-5
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  3
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          21
Model:               2
Model name:          AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor
Stepping:            0
CPU MHz:             3811.657
BogoMIPS:            7023.23
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           16K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            2048K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-5
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate ssbd ibpb vmmcall bmi1 arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
```

**I got some JS error in logs from my latest freeze, this has not come before**

```
02:10:07 gnome-shell: JS ERROR: ReferenceError: GLib is not defined
_sliderChanged/this._notifyVolumeChangeId  [1539560511.7105] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed bound -> bound
01:41:51 dhclient: DHCPACK of 172.16.0.4 from 172.16.0.1
01:39:56 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
01:39:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
01:39:01 kernel: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
01:39:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
01:37:51 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
01:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
01:16:56 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
01:09:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
01:08:34 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
01:02:13 kernel: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
01:02:13 kernel: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-10-15
01:02:13 systemd: Started Run anacron jobs.
01:00:13 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
00:59:23 systemd: Started Daily apt download activities.
00:59:22 packagekitd: resolve transaction /1414_eaeedcea from uid 1000 finished with success after 499ms
00:59:22 gnome-software: tried overwriting spotify key GnomeSoftware::FeatureTile-css from border-color: #000000;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
color: #000000;
outline-offset: 0;
outline-color: alpha(#ffffff, 0.75);
outline-style: dashed;
outline-offset: 2px;
background: url('/home/desktop/.cache/gnome-software/cssresource/d41109772367d9176255aae48ada07072724beca-banner-icon_WaLCF17.png') left center / auto 100% no-repeat, url('/home/desktop/.cache/gnome-software/cssresource/49fefcf8aa37528235d9e84184b84e8ffac44ea7-banner_dSwF9EF.png') center / cover no-repeat;; to border-color: #000000;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
color: #000000;
outline-offset: 0;
outline-color: alpha(#ffffff, 0.75);
outline-style: dashed;
outline-offset: 2px;
background: url('https://dashboard.snapcraft.io/site_media/appmedia/2017/12/banner-icon_WaLCF17.png') left center / auto 100% no-repeat, url('https://dashboard.snapcraft.io/site_media/appmedia/2017/12/banner_dSwF9EF.png') center / cover no-repeat;;
00:59:13 systemd: Starting Daily apt download activities...
00:58:07 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
00:50:43 canonical-livep: No payload available.
00:49:45 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
00:39:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
00:37:13 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
00:17:09 gnome-shell: Some code accessed the property 'WindowPreviewMenuItem' on the module 'windowPreview'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
00:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
00:16:18 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
00:12:58 gnome-system-mo: Allocating size to gnome-system-monitor 0x10442b0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
00:12:07 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:6c:b0:ce:3c:9a:77:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
00:10:35 snapd: autorefresh.go:387: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
```

**Update**

I have now been testing the hardware and I found fault in one of the RAM modules with memtest86. I have now been running without freeze for four days, before it could take up to four days before it froze so I'm thinking this was the cause

Comment: Post the output of `lscpu` !

Comment: @karel I have tried the methods mentioned in your link, but my computer is non-responsive, just black screen or a twisted picture of what was on the screen just frozen. I have also tried to ssh in form another computer and that to does not work

Comment: @abu_bua I have added lscpu to the post

Comment: I have same problem with ubuntu 18.04. If it's related to GDM, when the screen goes black, press `ALT+CTRL+F4`, and if you saw the tty console, press `ALT+CTRL+F2`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013710/ubuntu-17-10-crashes-to-console-sometimes

Comment: @karel I went to double check if my sysrq button was enable and it was not so I will try the REISUB method. But yeah I am also starting to think it might be hardware at this point

Comment: @mohammads I will try this method next time it happens

Comment: If you have another graphics card handy, swap it with the existing graphics card and check if it makes any difference in the random freezing.

Comment: @kerel I don't have another graphics card but I have two in my system now, could it worthwhile testing just one at a time?

Comment: Try these tips... set your "Wired Connection" profile to disable IPv6 (assuming that you're using a wired connection), disable all extensions in Chrome and Firefox, if your bluetooth is an external USB dongle, remove it, or if it's built-in, turn if off. See if things improve. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: The computer froze again, I tried the methods mentioned by mohammads and heynnema. I also tried the REISUB method that to did not work. I think I will start testing hardware next

Comment: The logs don't show anything that would cause a hang. Given it happens when using a browser, it may be graphics card related, so testing them individually might help. I had a similar issue caused by a graphics card fan failure. If it's not graphics, it might be some other h/w, in which case you'd have to start a process of elimination.

Comment: @KimPhillips I started with memtest86 but even that is having trouble booting so I'm trying to take some memory out and se if that is the cause. After this I will also try with one graphics card at a time. Thanks